# Android Navigation Global actions overlay previous fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm building an app using the Android Navigation Component, and I have a custom made side menu that when a destination is selected, my `MainActivity` creates a direction for one of my global actions in my `NavGraph` and navigates to it.

However, if I don't add a background color to the new fragment's layout, I can still see the previous fragment below the newly pushed fragment, and sometimes the old fragment can receive touch events as well.

Has anyone faced this before? Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening and how to prevent it? Shouldn't when I call `navController.navigate(directions)` make the previous fragment not visible any more?

I'm trying to build a complex navigation system with multiple destinations that use a single fragment with different parameters, and I've been facing a lot of issues with the new Navigation Component. Any help/ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the code in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`? It sounds like you have two instances of the `NavHostFragment` added at once.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I think you are right. I have a `BottomNavigationView` and I'm trying to get a different back stack for each tab, and after following google's advanced navigaiton examples, I ended up creating a `NavHostFragment` for each of my tabs. However, I have a single NavGraph for all of my tabs (while google has a different graph for each tab), and I initialize my `NavHostFragment` with that NavGraph id, which I think creates the problem. Do you have any idea how to create a `BottomNavigationView` that has the same navGraph for each of the tabs?

Comment: Having the same graph for every tab makes no sense, since they'd all show the same content then. You'd want to decompose your graph into a separate graph for each tab.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake . I guess the Navigation Component does not suit my navigation needs then. I have a single fragment that shows different content depending on what parameters I pass it and then many of the screens can show other fragments, thus I need them all in a single nav graph. I'll try to figure it out or scrap the navigaiton component completely and use the old fragment manager way if It does not support my case.

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work? You can certainly define different arguments for a destination in different graphs and use an <include> for common elements

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar problem where I have to set the background color, though I'm not using any custom side menu (rather a drawer layout configured in the standard way with menu xml). Setting the background color only serves to paper over the cracks because the enter/exit animation doesn't happen.